# Symlink on a folder inside a mounted drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, symbolic-link

Ok so i moved from windows to ubuntu 12.04 32bit yesterday and im still learning the folder structure etc of *nix systems. What im trying to do is create a symlink from my 2nd hard drive's, which is supposed to be mounted in every boot on /media/media, folder named Music (so /media/media/Music) to ~/Music.

Even though it works while im logged when i reboot the symlink breaks. Any ideas why?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the second drive to `fstab` so that it mounts on every boot. That's what I would do.

A good page on the subject is at [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) and a practical example is at [this site](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountwindowsfstab).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.